# Trying to get a date image inside my block

Tags: 7, blocks

I am trying to get a date image inside my block. For some reason, doing updates broke it.

I'm looking around and trying to change different settings, and look for different settings that may have been affected, it appears like there's something called "Content: Date(s)" in the area in question, however nothing I change in regards to it works.

Here's an image:

[image: Site with non-working date]

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I think it would be good to have a lot more of information. Which date do you try to change? Change from what to what? What have you already tried? Is this a view? How is the image in question generated (imagecache)? Did you clear the cache? And so on ...

Comment: I was seeing if modifying the display of my view would work.

It isn't that I want to change it - those big date boxes, for example, Mar 27 - are not showing up. At all. I want to fix that.